# Understanding the meaning of the capybara syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I want to understand what the following Capybara syntax means -

```
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="application-lines"]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a').click
```

I particularly don't understand the second attribute of the find method.

It would be great if someone could help me understand the syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not something specific of Capybara, that is an XPath, is used to navigate the elements of an XML document.

In this case is looking for a node with `id` `application-lines` and inside that element retrieving the second `div[2]`, with an `ul` element from which retrieves the second `li` and retrieves the `a` element inside it. All this ends up doing is a `click` on the `a` element found.

You can learn about XPaths here: [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp)